# Dividing Pandas Series into a few series of chars

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas Series of strings with length of exactly 3:

```
Column
abc
rgt
opx
cba
dtype: Object
```

I would like to get pandas df or, at least, distinct columns, where 1 series is the first element of series, 2nd is second ones, etc.
Expected output is:

```
df

    col1    col2    col3
0   a       b       c
1   r       g       t
2   o       p       x
3   p       b       a
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `str.split` with a trick lookahead regex:

```
(df['Column'].str.split('(?=.)', expand=True)
   .drop(0, axis=1).add_prefix('col')
)
```

regex: `(?=.)`: matches if there is a character after.

output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    b    c
1    r    g    t
2    o    p    x
3    c    b    a
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use list comprehension on Series and unpack string into characters in list to make row.

```py
pd.DataFrame([[*el] for el in series], columns=["col1","col2","col3"])
```